# JMeter - Avoid threads abrupt shutdown

Tags: apache, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a testPlan that has several transacion controllers (that I called UserJourneys) and each one is composed by some samplers (JourneySteps).

The problem I'm facing is that once the test duration is over, Jmeter kills all the threads and does not take into consideration if they are in the middle of a UserJourney (transaction controller) or not.

On some of these UJs I do some important stuff that needs to be done before the user logs in again, otherwise the next iterations (new test run) will fail.

The question is: Is there a way to tell to JMeter that it needs to wait every thread reach the end of its flow/UJ/TransactionController before killing it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as of version 5.1.1, you should request an enhancement at:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

The solution is to add as first child of [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) containing a JSR223 PreProcessor:

[image: Configuration]

The [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) will contain this groovy code:

```
    import org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopTestException;

    long startDate = vars["TESTSTART.MS"].toLong();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String testDuration = Parameters;
    if ((now - startDate) >= testDuration.toLong()) {
        log.info("Test duration "+testDuration+" reached");
        throw new JMeterStopTestException("Test duration "+testDuration+"reached ");
    } else {
        log.info("Test duration "+testDuration+" not reached yet");
    }
```

And be configured like this:

[image: JSR223 PreProcessor configuration]

Finally you can set the property **testDuration** in millis on command line using:

> -JtestDuration=3600000

If you'd like to learn more about JMeter and performance testing this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll open a feature request on Apache's website.